# How to open Outlook new mail window on server C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am using this link for open outlook new mail window.
[How to open Outlook new mail window c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148639/how-to-open-outlook-new-mail-window-c-sharp)

But It is working fine On Local machine but when I deployed it on server it shows below error.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Microoft office outlook is install on local machine not on server.It is required to install and configure outlook on server.
Plz help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't use outlook on the server if it is not installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using Outlook**

To send an email using outlook, we need to add a reference to the dynamic link library for Outlook which is called Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll
For the same follow the below steps:

Go to your solution explorer

Click on add a reference

Click on .Net Tab

Go through the DLL and select Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll 
correctly.

when you have selected the correct reference you select the “OK” button and this reference will be added to your project under references.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
//method to send email to outlook
public void sendEMailThroughOUTLOOK()
{
    try
    {
    // Create the Outlook application.
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    // Create a new mail item.
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    // Set HTMLBody. 
    //add the body of the email
    oMsg.HTMLBody = "Hello, Jawed your message body will go here!!";
    //Add an attachment.
    String sDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
    int iPosition = (int)oMsg.Body.Length + 1;
    int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
    //now attached the file
    Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\fileName.jpg", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
    //Subject line
    oMsg.Subject = "Your Subject will go here.";
    // Add a recipient.
    Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
    // Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
    Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("jawed.ace@gmail.com");
    oRecip.Resolve();
    // Send.
    oMsg.Send();
    // Clean up.
    oRecip = null;
    oRecips = null;
    oMsg = null;
    oApp = null;
     }//end of try block
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }//end of catch
}//end of Email Method
```

For more information [Open outlook](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/165548/C-Code-snippet-to-send-an-Email-with-attachment-fr)

Comment: This is working on local but not on server. I also have added DLL. Same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using standard .Net classes or any other components designed for the server-side execution. In case of Exchange Server account you can use EWS (Exchange Web Services), see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

Answer (score 0):

If you run that code on the server, who will see the newly created message? Even if there is a user logged in locally to the server, IIS runs without a desktop session.

If you want the message to be displayed on the *client*, that is where your code needs to run. Why not use a mailto url? It will work in any browser and the default email client will be opened. If you need something more sophisticated than that, you need to write your code in JavaScript and create an instance of the Outlook.Application object using `new ActiveXObject().` You can only do that in IE and your site must be trusted to do that.