# Open outlook new mail window from server c#

Tags: javascript, c#, email, outlook

I having a frunctionality in which user can select multiple product links and can choose an option to mail those links to anyone as a new outlook mail window will be opened. Everything is working fine on my local machine but on deployed link this functionality is not working and is throwing below exception:

> Exception Message  : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80010001): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with
>   CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the
>   following error: 80010001 Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)).

I saw a couple of solutions for this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861797/how-to-open-outlook-new-mail-window-on-server-c-sharp) and some code samples [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/cs2010samples) but nothing helped me.
Also before going for the c# code for opening new mail window, i also tried doing it in javascript but got an issue there as well ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284584/add-hyperlink-in-outlook-mail-body-from-javascript)).

Please help !!

Comment: you're going to have to post the code that is throwing this exception , otherwise this would be impossible to answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1436)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644441/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800a1436)

Answer (score 0):

See sending mail through outlook is not done by server side it should be done in client Side..

To open a link in mail sending client you can do

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

This will automatically open mail sending client in user machine