# Open C# generated Mail, Edit it, Send it in C#

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient, mailmessage

my Problem is as follows.
I generate a default Email(type of MailMessage) in C# and want to Send it through a smptclient. But before that I want to Open and Edit it in Outlook or whatever Email Program is installed. Right now I'm doing this:

```
message.Save(fileName, true);
Process.Start(fileName);
```

Save is an extension Method copied from [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328598/open-default-mail-client-along-with-a-attachment)

But now ofcourse the Mailprogramm tries to Send the Mail itself... I Need however an default Sender. So if I try to Send it through Outlook I get an Error Mail like :

> Ihre Nachricht hat einige oder alle Empfänger nicht erreicht.
>
> Betreff:   Test report 18.03.2016
>      Gesendet am:   18.03.2016 10:36
>
> Folgende(r) Empfänger kann/können nicht erreicht werden:
>
> Max Muster am 18.03.2016 10:36
>
> Diese Nachricht konnte nicht gesendet werden. Versuchen Sie es später erneut, oder wenden Sie sich an den
>   Netzwerkadministrator. Sie besitzen nicht die Berechtigung, die
>   Nachricht im Auftrag des angegebenen Benutzers zu senden. Fehler:
>   [0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524].

Which translated boils down to :
Couldn't deliver Mail. You don't have Permission to Send the Message from the specified User. Error: [0x80070005-0x0004dc-0x000524]
Sorry I don't have an English Error Message.

Is there any way to pass an specific SMPT Server to a mailObject? So that any Email program opening the Mail, will use this Server instead?

Comment: Here are a few question, What is a `default` Email? What is a default `Sender`? Nicht alle Menschen haben Deutsch als Muttersprache. Nicht so höflich!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148639/how-to-open-outlook-new-mail-window-c-sharp , look here. Edit the message and Send it