# Opening a new Outlook 2016 window with c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 and c#. 
My goal is to open a new Outlook window by clicking a button in a small program I wrote for learning reasons. 
The problem is that, as far as I know, the Office API [look here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook/) does not support Office 2016, or better said, any Framework over 2.0
I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148639/how-to-open-outlook-new-mail-window-c-sharp) slightly helpful comment by a user on this side, but they also suggest the Office API which doesn't work anymore.

I am very thankful for every helpful comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which Office interop files are used (to which Office version they belong) - you can still automate Office applications from .Net applications. So, just add a COM reference (for Microsoft Office Outlook) to your application and use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace FileOrganizer
{
    class Program
    {
        private void CreateMailItem()
        {            
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
            mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
            mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";                        
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
    }
}
```